# Pub/Sub push return 503 for basic scaling

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using Pub/Sub push subscription, ack deadline is set to 10 minutes, the `push` endpoint is hosted within AppEngine using `basic` scaling. 
In my logs, I see that some of the Pub/Sub (supposedly delivered to starting instances) push requests are failed with `503` error status and `Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request.` log message. The execution time for this request varies from 10 seconds (for most of the requests) up to 30 seconds for some of them. 
According to this article https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling `Deadlines` for HTTP request is 24 hours and request should not be aborted in 10 seconds. 
Is there a way to avoid such exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These failed requests are most likely timing out in the [Pending Request Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/glossary#pending_request_queue), meaning that no instances are available to serve them. This usually happens during spikes of PubSub messages that are delivered in burst and App Engine can't scale up quickly enough to cope with them.

One option to mitigate this would be to switch the scaling option to [automatic scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements) in your app.yaml file. You can tweak the `min_pending_latency` and `max_pending_latency` to better fit your scenario. You can also specify `min_idle_instances` to get idle instances that would be ready to handle extra load (make sure to also enable and handle [warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/configuring-warmup-requests))

Take into account though that PubSub will automatically retry to deliver failed messages. It will adjust the delivery rate according to your system's behavior, as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#quotas_limits_and_delivery_rate). So you may experience some errors during spikes of messages, while new instances are being spawned, but your messages will eventually be processed (as long as you have setup `max_instances` high enough to handle the load).

Comment: Automatic scaling has 60 seconds limit for request handling this limit doesnot fits my requirements is it possible to setup request queue properties for basi scaling?

Comment: Unfortunately not, that's why it's called "basic" scaling :) But this may just impact the service when there's a spike. It will throttle the execution rate for a while but the pending messages will eventually be processed. I've updated my answer with some more details.